# How to edit Xfce logout menu?

Tags: xfce, customization

I would like to customize the logout menu of Xfce session.

[image]

Which file do I need to edit to change the menu options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable options from the logout menu in `xfce4-settings-editor`.

From the terminal, you can use `xfconf-query`, i.e. as in

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -np '/shutdown/ShowSuspend' -t 'bool' -s 'false'
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -np '/shutdown/ShowHibernate' -t 'bool' -s 'false'
```

to remove "Suspend" and "Hibernate" options, respectively.

This does not disable these possibilities, it just removes the options from the dialog.

Comment: Great examples! I've added them to the official documentation. https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by changing parameters in Xfce's [kiosk mode](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/advanced#kiosk_mode) related files.

For example, to remove the Save Session button, follow these steps.

1. From the terminal, create a directory `sudo mkdir -v /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk`
2. Next, create this file: `sudo touch /etc/xdg/xfce4/kiosk/kioskrc`
3. Edit the file and add the following lines:

```
    [xfce4-session]
    SaveSession=NONE
```

4. Reboot your computer.

The option for saving your sessions will no longer be on the logout session menu.

You will need to take a look at the documentation for other customization options.

Comment: The question is about "to change the menu option", not only remove option.